# Ember js sorting a filtered array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am displaying a list of results, using a handlebars helper which loops over an array in the controller as below:

```html
{{#each results as |job|}}
    {{job-table-row model=job}}
{{/each}}
```

```js
results: function() {
    var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm'),
        results = this.get('content'),
        order = this.get('date_ordering'),
        status = this.get('Status'),
        if (searchTerm) {
                results = results.filter(function(item) {
                return item.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });
        }
        if (status) {
                results = results.filter(function(item) {
                return (item.get('status') == status);
            }
        });
} 
return results;
}.property('content', 'searchTerm', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'date_ordering', 'Status', 'Platform'),
```

I would like to add functionality to sort the 'created_at' column when the property 'date-ordering' receives a value:

```js
results: function() {
    var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm'),
        results = this.get('content'),
        order = this.get('date_ordering'),
        status = this.get('Status'),
        
        ...
          
        if ((order) && (order ===0)) {
            results = results.sort('created_at' sortAscending);
        }
        else if ((order) && (order ===1)) {
            results = results.sort('created_at' sortDescending);
        }
    });
} 
return results;
}.property('content', 'searchTerm', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'date_ordering', 'Status', 'Platform'),
```

Is it possible to do this in a way similar to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you suggested should work.

Alternatively, you could do the sorting through a different property:

```
sortedResults: Ember.computed.sort('results', 'sortProperties'),
sortProperties: function() {
  var order = this.get('date_ordering') ? "asc" : "desc";
  return ['created_at:' + order];
}.property('date_ordering')
```

changing the `each` helper to loop over `sortedResults`